# Partial ordering: is increasing pair equivalent with increasing subsequence

Tags: order-theory

An [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/889200/73561) on this site states that

For partial ordering $\leq$, the claims

1. every infinite sequence $x_1, x_2, \dots$ has an increasing pair, i.e., there exist $i < j$, such that $x_i \leq x_j$
2. every infinite sequence $x_1, x_2, \dots$ has increasing subsequence, i.e., there exist $i_1 < i_2 < \cdots$, such that $x_{i_1}\leq x_{i_2}\leq \cdots$.

are equivalent

### I wonder why is partial ordering needed here.

My thoughts:

Proving $2\Rightarrow 1$ is trivial: suppose 2 holds. Then, we have infinitely many such pairs.
Proving $1\Rightarrow 2$ is a bit harder:

Suppose 1 holds. Let $A_1$ be the set $A_1 = \mathbb{N}$. Consider the sequence $(x_i)_{i\in A_1}$ (the initial sequence). Then, we can find a pair of indices $i_1 < j_1$, such that $i_1 < j_1$ and $x_{i_1} \leq x_{j_1}$. We repeat the same for the sequence $(x_i)_{i\in A_0, i > j_1}$ and obtain $(i_2, j_2)$. By repeating this, we obtain infinitely many increasing pairs of indices $(i_k, j_k)$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$, such that $$i_1 < j_1 < i_2 < j_2 < i_3 < j_3 < \cdots$$
Let's store them in the set $B_1$.

Then, we consider the set of indices $A_2 = \{ j_k \mid (i_k, j_k)\in B_1 \}$ and the subsequence $(x_i)_{i\in A_2}$. Again, we can construct infinitely many increasing pairs that are stored in $B_2$. However, every such pair now corresponds to an increasing triplet. For example, if $x_{j_2} \leq x_{j_{7}}$, then we also have $x_{i_2}\leq x_{j_2} \leq x_{j_7}$.

Then, we consider the set of indices $A_3 = \{ j_k \mid (i_k, j_k)\in B_2 \}$, and the subsequence $(x_i)_{i\in A_3}$. Again, every pair we find, extends some increasing triplet to an increasing quadruple.

We continue with the procedure and gradually construct (many) increasing subsequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how you are generating an *infinite* subsequence. Of course, you are generating *finite* subsequences of arbitrary length, but this is not the same as generating an *infinite* one.

---

I guess for $1\implies 2$ you can try as follows. Let us assume $2$ does not hold for the sequence $x_1, x_2, x_3,\ldots$. Then this sequence reaches a *maximal* element, i.e. the element $x_{i_1}$ such that it is not $x_{i_1}\le x_j$ for any $j>i_1$. The reason why this is true is: otherwise you could just recursively create the increasing subsequence starting from $x_1$, and then keep finding new *bigger* elements one by one, further down the sequence.

Now take the sequence $x_{i_1+1}, x_{i_1+2}, x_{i_1+3}\ldots$ and apply the same logic. Again, as the original sequence was a counterexample for 2, this new sequence must also reach a maximum element $x_{i_2}$ such that $x_{i_2}\le x_j$ is false for all $j>i_2$.

And so on, we find indices $i_3, i_4,\ldots$ such that $x_{i_k}\le x_j$ is false for all $k$ and all $j>x_k$.

Finally, look at the subsequence $x_{i_1}, x_{i_2}, \ldots$: that subsequence does not have any pairs of elements in the right order: say if $u<v$, then $x_{i_u}\le x_{i_v}$ is false simply because $i_v>i_u$. This contradicts 1.

---

The reason they mention "partial" ordering in the linked answer is, probably, that the word "partial" is there just to remind you that it is not *necessarily* a total ordering (i.e. if $a\le b$ is false, $b\le a$ doesn't need to be true; $a$ and $b$ may be *incomparable*). It does not imply that the ordering *must not* be total, it just means the statement is valid even without that assumption. After all, the linked question was about curious properties of partial orderings!

Comment: "I don't see how you are generating an infinite subsequence." Now that this has been pointed out, I don't see it either. The problem is that each of the "intermediate" finite sequences might terminate at some point and we don't know which of them will "survive".