# Modell-Theory, Isomorphism

Tags: model-theory

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a language of the first-order logic with a binary relationsymbol $\stackrel{\cdot}{<}$ (and no other symbols).

Observe the following set $T$ of theorems:

$T:=\{\forall v_0\forall v_1 (v_0<v_1\to\exists v_2(v_0<v_2\wedge v_2<v_1)), \forall v_0\exists v_1\quad v_1<v_0,\forall v_0\exists v_1\quad v_0< v_1\}$

Also $\stackrel{\cdot}{<0}$ is supposed to be a linear order. It is missing, that $T$ has to include these axioms:

$\forall v_0\quad \neg v_0<v_0, \forall v_0\forall v_1(v_0<v_1\vee v_0=v_1\vee v_1<v_0), \forall v_0\forall v_1\forall v_2 (v_0<v_1\wedge v_1<v_2\to v_0<v_2)$

Task:

> Let $\mathcal{M}=(M,<_M)$ and $\mathcal{M}'=(M',<_M)$ be countable models of $T$.
>   Show, that $\mathcal{M}\cong\mathcal{M}'$

Hello,

I have a question to this task, and I would like to solve it with your help.
To show that $\mathcal{M}\cong\mathcal{M}'$

I have to show several things:

First of all there needs to exist a bijection

$\pi: M\to M'$ which states the following points:

a) $m_1<_M m_2\Leftrightarrow\pi(m_1)<_{M'}\pi(m_2)$

b) Let $c$ be a constant. Than holds $\pi(c^{\mathcal{M}})=c^{\mathcal{M}'}$

Normally this also includes function-symbols. But $T$ only contains the binary relation-symbol $\stackrel{\cdot}{<}$. Therefore I can skip this.

Is this everything what has to be done? Or do I miss something.
How do I include the set $T$?
The first thing I have to do now, is to give a suitable function $\pi$ and than show it holds a) and b).

Thanks in advance for your comments and tips.

Comment: The standard proof uses the [Cantor *Back and Forth* argument.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-and-forth_method)

Comment: Thank you. I did not know this method yet, but I looked it up. Do you have a source with a proof?

Comment: The link in the above comment provides a good outline of a proof for your case (densely ordered sets with no first or last element).  Also, I have mentioned a bunch of key words that will help locate other proofs. I am pretty sure for example that the question has come up on  MSE before.

Comment: [Here is one from MSE.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37151/showing-any-countable-dense-linear-ordering-is-isomorphic-to-a-subset-of-mat) There are undoubtedly several others.

Comment: Therefore the key point of the proof is to give a construction for the bijection $\pi$ using the properties of $T$, as hinted in the link. And $\pi$ will satisfy the mentioned points a) and b) then by construction of $\pi$.

Comment: Yes, or you can do it in two steps, an order preserving bijection from $M$ to the rationals, and one from the rationals to $M'$. And the constant symbol interpretations you mentioned as b) are irrelevant, there are no constant symbols.