# Seeking an isomorphism from $\langle\mathbb{Q},=,<\rangle\to\langle\mathbb{Q}\cap((0,1)\cup(2,3)),=,<\rangle$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, ring-isomorphism

As the question suggests, I am seeking an isomorphism from $$\langle\mathbb{Q},=,<\rangle\to\langle\mathbb{Q}\cap((0,1)\cup(2,3)),=,<\rangle.$$ I know for example that $$\frac{x}{2+2|x|}+\frac{1}{2}$$ is an isomorphism from $\langle\mathbb{Q},=,<\rangle\to\langle\mathbb{Q}\cap(0,1),=,<\rangle$. Also, I know that $$\frac{x}{2+2|x|}+\frac{5}{2}$$ is an isomorphism from $\langle\mathbb{Q},=,<\rangle\to\langle\mathbb{Q}\cap(2,3),=,<\rangle$. However, I'm not able to think of an obvious isomorphism from $\langle\mathbb{Q},=,<\rangle\to\langle\mathbb{Q}\cap((0,1)\cup(2,3))$.

My textbook defines a structure isomorphism as an injective function which preserves relations among elements. So if $x=y$ and $g$ is a bijection, then $g(x)=g(y)$. Similarly, $x<y$ implies $g(x)<g(y)$. Is such a construction even possible?

Comment: How can your maps be isomorphisms if they are not even injective? i.e. they render the same value for $x$ and $-x$.

Comment: Such a construction is definately possible. I don't know about an explicit formula but [any two countable dense linear orders without endpoints are isomorphic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37151/showing-any-countable-dense-linear-ordering-is-isomorphic-to-a-subset-of-mat/37158). This was first proven by Cantor.

Answer (score 3):

Let's define first an order-isomorphism from $(-\infty,\sqrt2)\cap\Bbb Q$
to $(0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$ and also one from $(\sqrt2,\infty)\cap\Bbb Q$
to $(2,3)\cap\Bbb Q$. The same idea works for both, so I'll just describe the
first. Putting these two order-isomorphisms together gives you the one you seek.

Let $(a_n)_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ be a strictly increasing doubly infinite sequence
in $(-\infty,\sqrt2)\cap\Bbb Q$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sqrt2$
and $\lim_{n\to-\infty}a_n=-\infty$.
Likewise,
Let $(b_n)_{n=-\infty}^\infty$ be a strictly increasing doubly infinite sequence
in $(0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$
and $\lim_{n\to-\infty}b_n=0$. Now define $f:(-\infty,\sqrt2)\cap\Bbb Q
\to(0,1)\cap\Bbb Q$ so that $f$ is maps each $[a_n,a_{n+1}]\cap\Bbb Q$
linearly to $[b_n,b_{n+1}]\cap\Bbb Q$.

Comment: +1. To motivate this for the OP: LStU "cuts" the rationals into two pieces, sending one to $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)$ and the other to $\mathbb{Q}\cap (2,3)$. Why do we "cut at $\sqrt{2}$"? Well, if we cut at - say - $17$ we'd have one rational left over, namely $17$. Luckily, $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, and that's what makes this work.