# The order type of the rationals.

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

Herewith another mind-numbingly naive question from a reader of philosophy.

My question concerns the order type of the rational numbers.

Omega squared seems a natural first choice, but obviously this does not look anything like the natural ordering of the rationals.

Is it known where the order type of Q occurs in the hierarchy of ordinal numbers?  Is there a known ordinal-arithmetic expression describing it a function of omega?

Finally, I really must buy a textbook on the subject of Set Theory.  Wiki is a fantastic resource and the maths pages are of exceptionally high quality, but I don't want to get into bed at night with my laptop.  Is there a standard, undergraduate text that could be recommended.

Comment: The order type of the rationals, which as Asaf points out is not an ordinal,  is often denoted with $\eta$.

Comment: Note we are all assuming that when you say "the rationals", you are referring to the rationals *along with* their usual ordering.

Comment: @Hurkyl  That's a very good point.  I really need to take a course on this subject!

Comment: @MJD Somehow I missed your comment earlier.  That's very helpful.  Not all order types are represented as ordinal numbers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The ordinals are order types of **well-ordered partial orders**. The rational numbers are not well-ordered, therefore their order type does not occur within the ordinal hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks again Asaf.  I really must do a course on this subject!

Comment: Yes. That is a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

E. Kampke's book on set theory, which I think has a Dover edition, has some material on the order type of the rationals.  It's not found among the ordinals because it's not well-ordered.  However, there's a proof, which I seem to recall goes back to Cantor, proving that any two countable linearly ordered sets without endpoints that are densely ordered (i.e. between any two points there's another) are order-isomorphic.

Comment: You probably have to add "countable" in your theorem.

Comment: [Relevant earlier discussion](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/13796/25554); it agrees with you that the theorem is due to Cantor. [Also relevant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37151/showing-any-countable-dense-linear-ordering-is-isomorphic-to-a-subset-of-mat).

Comment: @Michael Hardy.  Thanks for your recommendation and your interesting comment.

Comment: @GEdgar : Done.  I'm surprised I forgot that.  BTW, the same method of proof show that up to isomorphism there is only one countably infinite atomless Boolean algebra.